# Multiple duplicate title tags showing up in Webmaster Tools on Joomla 2.5 K2 site

Tags: joomla, duplicates, google-search-console, joomla-k2

I'm having an issue with my Joomla K2 site having a ton of duplicate title tags in Google Webmaster tools.  Here are some examples of one K2 article that has been flagged in Webmaster tools and is avaliable through many different links.

```
www.yakangler.com/articles/how-to/fishing/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/articles/news/events/special-events/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/articles/news/events/tournaments/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/articles/news/just-in/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/articles/news/new-products/boats/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/articles/news/new-products/fishing/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/articles/regional-fishing-reports/mid-atlantic-reports/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/guides-map/kayak-guides/item/1461-bob-bramblet
www.yakangler.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=1461:bob-bramblet&Itemid=509
```

I'm not sure how this article is available through all these different pathways, it's only published in a single category. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you have the same content duplicated in several categories. Or don't you have a SEF generator with old links?

Comment: issue is Joomla K2, you can take any article regardless of it's category and place it in the url path of another article of a different category and it will give you the article, not a 404 error. Was hoping someone has run into this before and found a solution to this SEO nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

update to 2.6.4 and create for the tags view a default menu point

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to 2.6.6,  make a menu link to "K2 categories" and don't select a specific category.
this will make all tags have that menu url as its default.